# ftp_connection in PHP, can I do things recursively?

Tags: php, recursion, ftp

I have code like this

```
$ftp_server = $_POST['server'];
$ftplogin = $_POST['login'];
$ftppass = $_POST['pass'];
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftplogin, $ftppass);
ftp_chmod($conn_id, 0777, $dir);
```

I want to know if I can change the file permissions of $dir to 777 recursively instead of just that one directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to do it manually. So AFAIK that command FTP "CHMOD" not support recursion.

Get a list of all the files, for example through function ftp_rawlist. Filter response and then have to use ftp_chmod on the result.

However, some servers can support CHMOD -R this command can be sent through the function ftp_site

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try ftp_site instead of ftp_chmod for Recursivly:

```
ftp_site($conn_id, 'CHMOD -R 0777 ' .$dir);
```

like exec() on your shell this will exec on ftp. At least i hope so.